# Fill Missing Quarters using Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, hana

I have data in table like this.

| Customer_Key | Customer_Name | Component | Region | Quarter | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 109 | General Motors | Piston | EAST | 2019-Q3 | 7,85,063.37 |
| 109 | General Motors | Piston | EAST | 2020-Q2 | 24,36,808.92 |
| 109 | General Motors | Piston | EAST | 2020-Q4 | 19,03,820.10 |
| 109 | General Motors | Piston | EAST | 2021-Q2 | 62,24,228.01 |
| 109 | General Motors | Piston | EAST | 2022-Q3 | 44,35,135.25 |
| 109 | General Motors | Piston | NORTH | 2020-Q2 | 0 |
| 109 | General Motors | Piston | NORTH | 2020-Q3 | -1,93,84,747.20 |
| 109 | General Motors | Piston | NORTH | 2021-Q2 | -4,78,786.77 |
| 109 | General Motors | Piston | NORTH | 2021-Q3 | 3,84,93,986.44 |
| 109 | General Motors | Piston | WEST | 2019-Q1 | 10,29,581.28 |
| 109 | General Motors | Piston | WEST | 2020-Q3 | 5,51,29,226.88 |

I want to fill/insert the rows with missing quarters from 2019-Q1 to 2022-Q4 with Sales as 0 for missing quarters and rest of the dimensions as it is.

For example: West has only two rows of quarter 2019-Q1 AND 2020-Q3. I also need other 14 rows of remaining quarters between 2019-Q1 AND 2022-Q4.

Sample fiddle data set: [Data Set](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/a819dNsKzdk8kXiYjkRNzz/0)

Can some please help with sql code to achieve the same ?

Comment: Create a dataset containing all the quarters you need, and then `LEFT JOIN` to your table.

Comment: I tried. Its isn't working. It turns all dimensions to Null except quarter

Comment: Here is the Sample dataset with Fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/a819dNsKzdk8kXiYjkRNzz/0

Comment: [Edit] your question, with the DDL and DML.

Comment: I just added a fiddle dataset. Please check

Comment: A fiddle should *compliment* your question, not be required to view to understand it.

Comment: Ohk. Do I need to provide more information to give more detail explanation of problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
CREATE TABLE #Fill_Gaps
    (Customer_Key int, Customer_Name varchar(14), Component varchar(6), Region varchar(5),Quarter varchar(7), Sales varchar(15))
;
    
INSERT INTO #Fill_Gaps
    (Customer_Key, Customer_Name, Component, Region, Quarter, Sales)
VALUES
    (109, 'General Motors', 'Piston', 'EAST', '2019-Q3', '7,85,063.37'),
    (109, 'General Motors', 'Piston', 'EAST', '2020-Q2', '24,36,808.92'),
    (109, 'General Motors', 'Piston', 'EAST', '2020-Q4', '19,03,820.10'),
    (109, 'General Motors', 'Piston', 'EAST', '2021-Q2', '62,24,228.01'),
    (109, 'General Motors', 'Piston', 'EAST', '2022-Q3', '44,35,135.25'),
    (109, 'General Motors', 'Piston', 'NORTH', '2020-Q2', '0'),
    (109, 'General Motors', 'Piston', 'NORTH', '2020-Q3', '-1,93,84,747.20'),
    (109, 'General Motors', 'Piston', 'NORTH', '2021-Q2', '-4,78,786.77'),
    (109, 'General Motors', 'Piston', 'NORTH', '2021-Q3', '3,84,93,986.44'),
    (109, 'General Motors', 'Piston', 'WEST', '2019-Q1', '10,29,581.28'),
    (109, 'General Motors', 'Piston', 'WEST', '2020-Q3', '5,51,29,226.88')
;

CREATE TABLE #Quarters
    (Quarters varchar(7))
;
    
INSERT INTO #Quarters
    (Quarters)
VALUES
    ('2019-Q1'),
    ('2019-Q2'),
    ('2019-Q3'),
    ('2019-Q4'),
    ('2020-Q1'),
    ('2020-Q2'),
    ('2020-Q3'),
    ('2020-Q4'),
    ('2021-Q1'),
    ('2021-Q2'),
    ('2021-Q3'),
    ('2021-Q4'),
    ('2022-Q1'),
    ('2022-Q2'),
    ('2022-Q3'),
    ('2022-Q4')
;

create table #temp (Customer_Key int, Customer_Name varchar(14), Component varchar(6), Region varchar(5),Quarter varchar(7))

--insert into #temp(Customer_Key,Customer_Name, Component, Region,Quarter)
--Select distinct Customer_Key,Customer_Name, Component, Region,Quarters
--from #Fill_Gaps A, #Quarters B  

 ---OR
 insert into #temp(Customer_Key,Region,Quarter)
Select distinct Customer_Key,Region,Quarters
from #Fill_Gaps A, #Quarters B

update t
set Customer_Name=fg.Customer_Name,Component=fg.Component
from  #temp t
inner join #Fill_Gaps fg on fg.Customer_Key=t.Customer_Key

select t.Customer_Key , t.Customer_Name, t.Component , t.Region ,t.Quarter,isnull(fg.Sales,0)Sales 
from #temp t
left join #Fill_Gaps fg on fg.Customer_Key=t.Customer_Key and t.Quarter=fg.Quarter and t.Region=fg.Region

drop table #Fill_Gaps,#Quarters,#temp
```