# SQL - how to duplicate records (self-join?)

Tags: sql, hana

I'm struggling to find a best-performing solution to the following problem.

I have a financial dataset that contains rows aggregated on a period level. The issue is, if an account doesn't have a year-to-date value on a certain period, the row does not exist.

I would like to write a query that would create that row with a "0" value the best performing way possible.

My current way of thinking would be to cross-join ALL periods with accounts. Then full-join that table with the source table again and create a new column that takes the YTD value, if not, take 0.

**Source table:**

| Period | Account | YTD Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 202201 | FI3030 | 10 |
| 202203 | FI3030 | 24 |

**Expected result:**

| Period | Account | YTD Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 202201 | FI3030 | 10 |
| 202202 | FI3030 | 0 |
| 202203 | FI3030 | 24 |

Comment: I assume you meant to type "if an account doesn't have [...]"

Comment: You presumably have a table `periods` defining the values `202201`, `202202` and so on?

Comment: And a table `accounts` defining the value `FI3030` and other accounts?

Comment: Can you add your current query and explain the issue with its performance? Performance is tightly bound to a specific product so please TAG your RDBMS.

Comment: @MarkRoberts 's question is very important. In adding you should explain how can we gain Account value, and if you are trying to obtain a record into your table or you just want a resultset (sql query). Which dialect?

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I updated my question. Source system is SAP HANA views.
To be clear, the "source table" I specified is the table as-is. No joins being done by myself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fill Missing Quarters using Sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72408493/fill-missing-quarters-using-sql)

Comment: Your challenge here is finding a way to know that 202202 exists and that you want it.  Is there a period dimension somewhere that you can SELECT DISTINCT Period from ?

Answer (score 0):

The is called a datespine when you are using dates. I notice your periods are numeric so I guess it's not really a datespine but the concept is similar.

Here's the general concept:

1. Select unique accounts
2. Select unique periods
3. Cross Join (cartesian join) these to create every possible combination of account and period
4. Outer Join #3 to your data

Pseudo code:

```
SELECT A.Account, A.Period, B.YTD_Value
FROM
(
  SELECT * 
  FROM 
    (
      SELECT Period 
      FROM ????? 
      GROUP BY Period
    ) AS Unique_P 
  CROSS JOIN (
      SELECT Account 
      FROM source_table 
      GROUP BY Account
    ) AS Unique_A
) AS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN source_table AS B
ON A.account = B.account
AND A.period = B.period
```

I prefer writing with CTE's where possible for readability:

```
WITH CTE_periods AS
(
      SELECT Period 
      FROM ????? 
      GROUP BY Period
    )
,CTE_accounts AS
(
      SELECT Account 
      FROM source_table 
      GROUP BY Account
    )
,CTE_combos AS (SELECT * FROM period CROSS JOIN account)
SELECT A.account, A.period, B.YTD_Value
FROM CTE_combos AS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN source_table AS B
ON A.account = B.account
AND A.period = B.period
```

Comment: In the outer join, should I use coalesce to grab the account code from either table A and B?

Comment: Where does the term *“datespine“* come from? The technique to outer join a reference set is well established but I’ve never seen this term used for it.

Comment: @LarsBr. thats a great question. I myself didnt start using the term until I saw it being used in the Rasgo and dbt community... I think I've seen it used in SAS as well but I'm not really sure where that term comes from.

Comment: @JeroenBeunckens you grab the account code from step 3 (which is from step 1) this means that it'll always be there.  The OUTER JOIN to your real data (lets call table B) will only contain that value when the join had a match, so it will be null otherwise. So if you consider step 3 as A and your original data as B,  then SELECT A.Account, A.Period, B.YTDValue